# Search as second word in SQLite android

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I might have 2 words or 3 words or more.

For example :

*Buah Mangga*

I want to search *Buah Mangga* with only typing ***mangga***

How could this be achieved ? I already running many query but still no result.

This is my query :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select kode_produk, nama_produk from produk where nama_produk like '% "+ keyword +" %' or nama_produk like '%"+ keyword +"' or nama_produk like '"+ keyword +" %' and status_produk = '1' order by nama_produk ASC", null );
    res.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: what query you have tried?

Comment: see my updatet post

Comment: which language ?? I am sure language must have a more cleaner way .

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Android java language

Comment: why nama_produk 3 times?

Comment: Because i didn't know what i have to do. I just want to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

try

```
db.rawQuery( "SELECT kode_produk, nama_produk 
              FROM produk 
              WHERE nama_produk like ? AND status_produk=? 
              ORDER BY nama_produk ASC", 

              new String{"%Mangga%", "1"} 
           );
```